# Alamofire Parameter missing in response

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, alamofire

I install pod file of `Alamofire` for calling web service and successfully retrieve data when there is no parameter pass to web service but when I try to pass parameter It shows this parameter missing.

**Here is my code:**

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["client_id": "1","user_token":"A4YkkH5FdTbRCI8Mk98s"]
let url = "http://***********/index.php/Web_api/get_client_profile"
Alamofire.request(url , method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if response.result.value != nil{
                    print(response.result.value)
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print(response.result.error)
                break

            }
        }
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
{
      "message : client_id parameter missing",
      "Code : 500"
}
```

What I am doing wrong ? Please help me with it.
Thank you

Comment: No problem with it, Its not case sensitive from php side

Comment: Have you test with postman yet? This is server side error, have almost nothing to do with this code

Comment: I have tested it into postman, I am getting data and I also implemented it with afnetworking , its working but in alamofire its not working @Tj3n

Comment: What is this type `Parameters` ? It should be `[String:AnyObject]`

Comment: yeah, it is but I want to pass multiple parameters

Comment: try change from `Parameters ` to `[String:AnyObject]`

Comment: Try this HUD library for iOS in swift https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head for like 6 Hours I figured a different approach, here is a way of calling it, which works:

```
var request: Alamofire.Request? {
    didSet {
        oldValue?.cancel()
    }
}

func loadDataFromServer(message:String?) {
    // Prerequisites for Connection to Server
    let timeParameter =  self.getLastTimeStamp()
    let url = "http://your.amazing.url/path/component/classs"
    let parameter = ["timestamp":timeParameter]

    //sho hud only of there is no data listed
    if message != nil {
        HUD.show(HUDContentType.label("Loading.."))
    }

    self.request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:parameter)
    if let request = request as? DataRequest {
        request.responseString { response in
            PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
            do{
                let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSDictionary

                //Save and Fetch
                self.saveTimestamp(dictionary: dictionary, wsEntity: "Section")
                self.saveDataInPersisanceStorage(articalDictionary: dictionary)
                self.fetchDatafromCore()

                //HUD.flash(.success, delay:1.0)
            }catch{
                //HUD.flash(.error, delay:1.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try it and let you know

Comment: Thank you for this, I am too much tired of calling it but your method did it for me. Thank you